# Java . Save console input with loops to array lists and convert it to a string array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, java.util.scanner

This is my try to save console input into a array list and convert it to a string Array.

There are no syntax errors but it wont work how it should do.
For proposal and tips I would be very grateful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoeffelSprache
{
    public LoeffelSprache()
    {
    }
    public void translation ()
    {
        System.out.println("Insert your Text here");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s= sc.next(); 

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.next();   
            list1.add(s);
        }
        String [] words = new String [list1.size()];
        words=list1.toArray(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `main` method? Are you calling `translation()`?

Comment: `...but it wont work how it should do.`  -- And how should it work?  How does it work?  You need to include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in your question.  Please read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I just want to save console input into an array. I use BlueJ so the main method is not necessary. public void translation () is the constructor and its empty.

Comment: Why don't u think the contents are being saved to the array? Your `Array` is defined locally in `translation()` and as far as I can tell you aren't doing anything with the `Array` so how do you know it's not being stored in `words`?

Comment: `public void test (){
        for (String a:words) {
            System.out.println(a);`  it says there is not variable "words"

Comment: thanks so far you are right this is my test method

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LoeffelSprache {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Insert your Text here");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
         arrList.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

     String[] strArr = new String[arrList.size()];
     arrList.toArray(strArr);
    for(String str:strArr){
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

}

Enjoy!

```
    public static boolean translation() {
    System.out.println("Insert your Text here");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    String[] words = new String[list1.size()];
    list1.toArray(words);
    test(words);
    return true;
}

public static void test(String[] words) {
    for (String a : words) {
        System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the method type it wont compile because the funktion add. must be a boolean type. When I try to give it a return true statement the problem still exist

Comment: ` public boolean translation ()
    {
        System.out.println("Insert your Text here");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s= sc.next(); 

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

     
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sc.next();   
            list1.add(sc.hasNextLine());

        }
        
        String [] words = new String [list1.size()];
        list1.toArray(words);
        return true;
    }

    public void test (){
        for (String a:words) {
            System.out.println(a); `

Comment: public static boolean translation() {
  System.out.println("Insert your Text here");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   list1.add(sc.nextLine());
  }
  String[] words = new String[list1.size()];
  list1.toArray(words);
  test(words);
  return true;
 }

 public static void test(String[] words) {
  for (String a : words) {
   System.out.println(a);

Comment: dont use the sc.next option; as this will iterate past the first value and just take into account the second value in the scanner.